# Consider resizing the asset ahead of time, supplying a cacheWidth parameter and cacheHeight parameter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-image

I'm new to flutter, I'm using flutter web.
and trying to apply and backdrop filter to an image.
this is my code :

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WebsiteBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebsiteBackground({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/office1.jpeg'),
        ),
      ),
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps spitting this error for me

```
 ======== Exception caught by painting library ======================================================
The following message was thrown while painting an image:
Image assets/images/office1.jpeg has a display size of 3024×1732 but a decode size of 6000×4000, which uses an additional 97721KB.

Consider resizing the asset ahead of time, supplying a cacheWidth parameter of 3024, a cacheHeight parameter of 1732, or using a ResizeImage.

====================================================================================================
[{"id":655,"result":{"value":"macOS","type":"Response","method":"ext.flutter.platformOverride"}}]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

**Edit: Fixed thank to @Ruchit' comment by changing the following**

```
image: AssetImage('assets/images/office1.jpeg'),
```

To

```
image: ResizeImage(AssetImage('assets/images/office1.jpeg'),
              width: 1000, height: 1000),
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i am assuming what's happening is you have a image which dimensions are 3024×1732 but you are rendering you image at dimensions 6000×4000, which a heavy work for flutter. so flutter is suggesting you specify the image dimension early so it prerender your image.

For that you use ResizeImage() class, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ResizeImage-class.html.